# ElasticSearch Indexing Confluence pages

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, confluence, elasticsearch-plugin

Can ElasticSearch index Confluence pages?
There are a lot of river plugins but none for Confluence. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html

Although there is a github project https://github.com/obazoud/elasticsearch-river-confluence but the last commit is a year ago, so I guess it's not up-to-date.

Comment: Here's an option if you're using confluence version 3 or 4: http://www.searchtechnologies.com/elasticsearch-connector-confluence.html but it doesn't appear to be free

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a free connector.

Comment: @maestr0, I guess it is too late for answer but you could try to read Confluence content right from the database (I guess BODYCONTENT table). I don't know if it is legal according to Atlassian license but it can be safe for sure as long as you only read from database. Unfortunatelly you must to write some converter yourself - for example to bulk insert data to ElasticSearch.

Comment: theres a chapter in confluence doc: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-up-an-external-search-tool-to-index-confluence-51871758.html

Comment: It looks like Confluence once tried to support Elasticsearch but it never go past experimental state: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/confluence-site-search-or-index-returns-elasticsearch-error-876855086.html
Rivers are outdated so I guess we're currently limited to crawling or reading the db directly.

Answer (score 1):

[Elasticsearch deprecated river](https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers).

Elasticsearch has a solution built over it called workplace search which could [connect to confluence](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/workplace-search/current/workplace-search-confluence-server-connector.html) for ingesting data.

Ideally, you might need to do it by the Confluent API via a script to Elasticsearch. You might also need to use the "ingest-attachment" plugin if you need to parse PDF content.